# WMI and MS directshow

Tags: wmi, directshow

I am gethering all hardware information for users is there any way to check if end user has [MS Directshow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) available ?

Comment: How can one NOT have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time DirectShow maybe not be available is on a Win95 without DirectX installed. Since Win98 it is a default component of the system. It is also unavailable if you are writing a Win8 Metro app, here you need to use Media Foundation. But for Win8 Desktop apps it's still available.

If you really really really want to test if it is available, then try to create a Filter Graph.

```
IGraphBuilder *pGraph = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL,
                 CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
```

If `hr` is not `S_OK` or `pGraph` still `NULL` then it is not available.

Or there is another possible time DirectShow or parts of it are not available: if someone has totally messed up his system and deregistered the needed COM dll's!